# What does ' Loyalty gave way to desire and Garrett' mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am wondering what this expression means.
It is from the movie 'Flipped' and here is the rest of the sentence.
'Loyalty gave way to desire and Garrett, the turncoat told Sherry what I was up to.'

In case you need to know the situation...

'Bryce,the main actor, asked out a girl Sherry because he wants the other girl,Julie, to lose interest in him. Sherry became aware of his plan because his best friend, Garrett told her because Garrett took an interest in Sherry himself.' and the Bryce saying the sentence that I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that was just a misplaced comma. [Quote marks for clarity only, not what you'd actually write]

Loyalty gave way to desire, and "Garrett the turncoat" told Sherry what I was up to.

Answer (score 2):

If Garrett were loyal to Bryce he would not reveal Bryce's motives. However Garrett desires Sherry, and in order to benefit himself and his desires sets aside his loyalty and tells Sherry.

Answer (score 2):

'Loyalty gave way to desire and Garrett, the turncoat told Sherry what I was up to.' In another simple rephrasing: loyalty gave way to Garrett's desire for Sherry. He became a [turncoat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turncoat) ( a traitor): he told Sherry what I was up to.

Meaning: Garrett the best friend who is supposed to be loyal to his friend Bryce betrayed him instead, telling Sherry what Bryce  was up to, because of his (Garrett) desire for Sherry.